# Can guns be rendered unusable by changing the atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, environment, atmosphere, firearms

I have an idea for a story in a post-apocalyptic setting where guns and other explosive devices unusable or otherwise impractical.

Is it possible to do this by changing the atmosphere (either by adding, removing, or changing the proportions of the chemicals that make up the standard earth atmosphere)?

The resulting atmosphere must be capable of supporting life, although it would be acceptable if human life required artificial support (e.g. portable supplementary oxygen supplies).   Ideally, I would like to avoid removing oxygen completely; instead I want to change the environment the minimum amount to prevent combustion.

Comment: When you say "prevent combustion" do you mean no fires can sustain themselves anymore? That's a lot more than just guns.

Comment: There was an Australian author I read a few decades ago who had nearly exactly that as a plot line.  I can't remember for the life of me his name, Jack something I think.  Giant space-battleships circled Earth and enforced it, I think, rather than actually changing the world.  And maybe it was electronics and not gunpowder, actually, hrm.

Comment: @Joe: You may be thinking of Sean McMullen, either his "Souls in the Great Machine" (1999) or "The Miocene Arrow" (2000) or "Eyes of the Calculor" (2001). Novels in the Greatwinter sequence.

Comment: @a4android I am!  Thanks for reminding me!!

Comment: @Joe Glad to help. He was the most likely candidate.

Comment: Don't know if this fits your setting, but with early guns they had a lot of trouble keeping the gunpowder dry. Basically couldn't use guns at all in the rainy weather. If the atmosphere is extremely humid, it may render the early models of firearms completely impractical, then modern firearms, for which it is not a problem, may never be invented. (Unless, of course, they brought modern firearms from outer space).

Comment: Something like [cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding) could be it, with something in the atmosphere that cleans the metal of any contaminants. Weapons resistant to this (vacuum guns, or guns with lubricants resistant to it) would be the only ones left.

Comment: Extreme, continuous turbulence would make guns more or less ineffective after a few meters. It won't do much for explosives though.

Comment: @Schwern my goal is to present a version of our modern world that has collapsed, and in the shadows of that society violent gangs form... but don't use guns.

Comment: Modern guns work in the vacuum of space... In theory at least. All The energy and reaction material is inside the brash cartridge. If the atmosphere were thicker,  that would mitigate guns. Bullet do poorly in a swimming pool.

Comment: Non-science: Dies the Fire ("spirits did it").  Sorta Science based: John Ringo's There Will be Dragons - energy transfer net takes energy from everything above a certain level.

Comment: It's curious to me how many 'post apocalyptic' stories revolve around guns being absent.

Comment: @Joe. "Souls in The Great Machine" had guns, they regularly duelled with them. It was electronic technology that was banned and the ban was enforced by a belt of satellites that lasered anything emitting electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @Shadow503 A higher oxygen content means fires would start more easily and burn more fiercely. That's nowhere near having the entire atmosphere explode. For that to happen it would need to contain oxygen *and fuel*.

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to store enough energy in the molecules of the air + have it released by extremely high velocity movement. Could be specially designed molecules or an unplanned side effect of something. When a bullet begins to travel it pushes air extremely quickly, the air flows around the bullet, and so much energy is suddenly released that the bullet is smashed. It drops to the ground. Or maybe rips apart the gun if it happens in the barrel. Also works for explosions. Low velocities like walking, running, driving a car don't trigger it so everyone is safe doing day to day things.

Comment: Removing guns from a post-apocalyptic world is surely as simple as saying all the munitions factories (and any other ammunition-manufacturing capabilities) were destroyed during the apocalypse?  Once stockpiled ammo runs out, guns are defunct.

Comment: There exist more bullets than people. It's going to be a while before they run out after the apocalypse.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make the atmosphere more combustible by adding lots of methane or other super-volatile gases.  It won't stop the guns from functioning, but it will make using them suicidal for the wielder.

It does not even have to be super volatile gasses (as the presence of such might prevent human to walk around without life support systems), it is enough to increase the oxygen concentration to slightly over 30% to make it quite dangerous to fire rounds. If the atmospheric oxygen concentration is over 30%, then even [wet plants will ignite and burn](https://www.fieldmuseum.org/fire-and-atmospheric-oxygen) if there is anything to light them on fire, yet humans and animals will not be in any danger from breathing it (it will even slightly enhance performance when using your muscles). As a bonus, you will also get giant insects as their [size limit](http://phys.org/news/2006-10-giant-insects-oxygen-air.html) is a function of how well oxygen can diffuse in to their bodies.

Comment: This is an approach I hadn't considered, but it's a very good idea; I've edited my question to clarify that guns have to be *impractical*, rather than simply non-functional.

Comment: This is not dissimilar to the Frank Herbert "mutual annihilation" interaction of lazguns and personal body shields.  Basically if a lazgun hits a personal shield, it will annihilate both shooter and victim.  And because lazguns protect from projectile and small explosive weapons, it forces combat to be largely hand to hand bladed combat.

Comment: If you are trying to be scientifically accurate then an atmosphere that is a combustible mixture is a non-starter. Even in the absence of sources of ignition such as lightning, easily oxidized gases will oxidize slowly, but I think on a timescale of weeks. An atmosphere stable enough to count as an atmosphere can't be so unstable that it can be ignited by a gunshot. ... But what if there are widespread massive leaks of odorless explosive gases from underground? You'd never know if it was safe to strike a match. Hmm. Henry may have something.

Comment: This will make remote attacks easier. Unless whole planet blows and in that case I would worry about life every day.

Comment: @MarkFoskey "An atmosphere stable enough to count as an atmosphere can't be so unstable that it can be ignited by a gunshot." Not true! In fact, the earth itself was like this during the Carboniferous period: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous#Rocks_and_coal

Comment: *"As a bonus, you will also get giant insects as their size limit is a function of how well oxygen can diffuse in to their bodies."* -- For certain definitions of the word "bonus" :P

Comment: Building on @MarkFoskey's comment, the atmosphere can only have this condition locally, such as "springs" of volatile gasses... _on the surface._ If tunnels and caverns play a part in the story, leaking gas deposits are much more plausible (though you have to resort to flame-less light sources). This might not make using guns impossible _everywhere,_ but in enough places that it suits your purposes. Also, consider caverns or other natural/artificial geographic structures that could keep those gasses dangerously contained

Comment: Note that this would not only make guns and explosives unusable, but also cars, matches, and anything else which could potentially ignite the gas.

Comment: I can make guns usable in this environment.

Comment: @Mrkvička,  Thanks for enhancing my brief answer!  I can always use more points.  FYI : It seems to be an acceptable practice around here to start a new answer with something like "Building on HenryTaylor's answer".  In that way, you would get the points for the enhancements you offer and people would know which ideas are yours rather than mine.

Comment: @Stephen: Seems that the lazgun / shield mutual destruction would lend itself to creating a large supply of one-shot disposable lazguns.

Comment: You are limited to the upper end of the 02% (FIO2), since higher FIO2% results in  absorption atelectasis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atelectasis#Absorption_.28resorption.29_atelectasis

Comment: @ZanLynx The problem with that approach is the shield+lasgun interaction was comparable to a nuke.  There isn't really a safe way to do it.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks, now I need to go and finish that series....  :)  (I read the first three.)

Comment: @Shadow503 Are you referring to the high oxygen content. I don't think every lightning bolt and volcanic event burned the world down, so the atmosphere wasn't particularily explosive...

Comment: Would a single spark cause the whole (or a large part) of the atmosphere to detonate?

Comment: Making the atmosphere itself combustible (while a fun idea) might actually make guns and explosives MORE dangerous. If you can leave an explosive in a hotel room, leave town, and the next day it explodes and the atmosphere over an entire country ignites you might get a lot more people dying from explosions. Same for a remote triggered gun blowing up eg an entire house. Makes it easier to do more damage. Gangs and cartels might be blowing up houses left and right.

Comment: @Shadow503 - I was referring to a combustible  mixture, such as oxygen and methane, which has never made up the earth's atmosphere. I do not think simply a high oxygen concentration, as existed in the Phanerozoic, would make guns too dangerous to fire. Saying that wet plants can catch fire is a far cry from saying that a gunshot would ignite the atmosphere itself.

Comment: What, @Steve-O, you're not looking forward to riding a giant cockroach to work??

Comment: This is more of a reason to use drones, and missile systems. not to mention we'd probably have a set of methane burners around anything important that would set fire to any gas near the vicinity.

Comment: @ HenryTaylor: I should perhaps have made my own answer, but I liked yours and originally only wanted to add my addition to it as a comment, which I ironically did not have enough rep to do at the time. In the end, I don't really care if I get cred for it or not, I'm just happy to have added something.  @MarkFoskey An enriched oxygen environment greatly enhances the risk of fires and while the gunshot will not ignite the atmosphere itself, it will be enough to risk setting the environment around the shooter ablaze.

Answer (score 43):

Considering the propellant in *all* munitions that I'm aware of (except fuel-air bombs and spud guns) is self-oxidising, that is to say, it requires *nothing* from the atmosphere (guns and bombs work fine underwater or *even in space* - well... they work fine *once* anyway) I'm inclined to say that, other than some kind of corrosive atmosphere eating the shells, that there's probably not much you can do about atmospherically preventing munitions from functioning.

However, as combustion engines *are* dependent on the atmosphere to run (they get their oxidiser - oxygen - from the air) so there is probably something you could do to stop the engines, maybe something that causes them to gum up or something that makes them rust really fast (really salty sea air works well)

Comment: Automatic and semi-automatic guns will fire underwater, but they typically won't cycle the next round into the chamber.  Air that's dense or viscous enough to make that happen wouldn't be breathable, though.

Comment: And forgot to mention, even that wouldn't defeat a revolver.  A revolver uses the movement of the trigger to rotate the mechanism, not force from exhaust gases.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I should probably mention that shouldn't I, range would be terrible too, 2 meters *max* before the bullet falls to the floor (thanks Mythbusters)

Comment: I was trying to remember if the Mythbusters had ever tested firing a gun underwater.  I definitely remember the shooting-into-water episode, where they found that the higher powered the weapon, the more the bullet just disintegrated on impact with the water.  (Since they're designed to be soft and do that when hitting people; armour piercing rounds might have just stopped quickly without fragmenting.)

Comment: @Sam 2 meters *max* for bullet-designed-for-air fired from a gun-designed-for-air, of course. 40 years ago, *effective* underwater range was [30m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APS_underwater_rifle). I dunno what's current hi-tech can do. Although, considering origin history of that gun, maybe there were no advances.

Comment: Really really salty air doesn't stop engines (at least not in the short term), or marine engines would not exist.

Comment: @Johnny Not under normal conditions, no, but it was one of the few situations that I could think of that could at least plausibly bring most engines to a halt *eventually*, it's never going to be instant, but without sufficient maintenance and spare parts (which I imagine would be uncommon after an apocalypse) pretty much all steel engines will die (although an all-aluminium engine with ceramic bearings could probably keep going *far* longer)

Comment: @Daerdemandt 60m is current [See supercavitating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_firearm). But thats still pretty shitty overall.

Answer (score 20):

If you are willing to go for a bit of hand waving: There are nanoparticles in the air that makes it act like a [non-Newtonian fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid), or oobleck.

Usually, the nanoparticles float around completely unnoticed, like dust. But if something starts moving very quickly, the air around it seems to solidify, destroying and stopping the object. Then the air quickly reverts to normal. Maybe it kicks in at high speed, near the speed of sound. This would make guns infeasible. You could also make it depend on acceleration instead - this would still allow high speed vehicles or planes in the affected air, but still rule out guns. It might also have an effect on arrows. Just make sure people don't get killed when they sneeze.

I imagine the way it works is that the nanoparticles are tiny electronic floaters, like large molecules or nanoscale transcievers. They have a kind of electric field between them. If one starts to move rapidly between the others, they induce some power in the particle - like if you move a conductor through an electric field. This in turn causes the particles to attract each other. But if they come closer together, they also repel each other - the result is that they quickly form a long range lattice or crystal. The surrounding air is also locked into the lattice, via an interaction between the activated particles and the air molecues. Either something like static electricity, or a long-range version of [Van der Waals-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force). The result is that the viscosity rises quickly, and the air becomes very thick or even solid.

Note that my explanation how it works uses a lot of "kind of" and "something like" and is total BS :-). So you'd need to be comfortable with "nanotechnology as magic", or work a bit on the science of it first.

Comment: Everyone will have pulmonary fibrosis. Everyone.

Comment: Well then, aehm, break out the portable oxygen supplies :-)

Comment: @DOS4004 How long would one go breathing without a filter to get 50% chance of getting pulmonary fibrosis? If something reasonable, it can be turned from obstacle to flavour.

Comment: Probably on the order of years (everyone over 20 who never wore a filter would probably have it). It depends on the concentration, but sawdust might be similar.

Comment: I think this one is the coolest idea on the page. As a bonus, everyone gets a little bit more iron in their diet.  I feel like you could handwave the pulmonary fibrosis pretty easily, maybe people have nanoparticle immune systems from before the collapse or something.

Comment: Of course then you would just decrease muzzle velocity, while increasing mass of the bullet, up to the point where you would have harpoon guns, or gunpowder-"crossbows" or something like that.

Comment: If you go from nanoparticles to nanobots, they can be made harmless to organic tissue by "programming" them to recognize and exit the body.

Answer (score 11):

if its post-apocalyptic you can just be truthful and have making the bullets difficult.  Making modern propellants is not something you can do at home, especially the primer. reloading bullets is based on being able to buy these materials. Using black powder (which you can make) in modern firearms, will gum them up rather quickly.
preventing the making of explosives is much more tricky. 
basically you might want to look at a different way to disable firearms than changing the atmo, since life still basically runs off of really slow combustion of carbon, so any change that prevents one will prevent the other.

Comment: Actually hand casting bullets is still practiced.  Current modern firearms like the 38 special actually started as black powder weapons.  As indicated, black powder can be made.  Actually, nitropowder can also be made though with significant danger and expertise needed.  The main problem is the primer.  There are examples of even those being made by insurgents.

Comment: primers made from other manufactured goods, like matches, which would be even rarer in a post-apocalyptic setting. but you are right there are some modern firearms that can handle black powder, but most will not, especially anything semi to fully automatic.The bullet and casing are easy, propellant and primer are the hard parts.

Comment: so back to flintlock muskets (most black powder still rely on external primers) but you won't see many modern firearms for very long. How post, post-apocalyptic are we talking.

Comment: @John `How post, post-apocalyptic are we talking` A span of time no more than 2 to 3 decades after the Event.

Comment: @Blackbeagle Production of guncotton doesn't require chemistry higher than they teach at schools. Access to materials and equipment would be needed, though, to produce batches of consistent qualities (vital for accuracy). Primer would be a problem indeed, but that still is not that bad. College-level knowledge of chemistry would probably suffice to produce something safe enough.

Comment: @Daerdemandt - yeah, the guncotton would be easy, but what I was thinking about was that in the more energetic powders, it was boosted by soaking in nitroglycerin - which requires somewhat more respect.  Regarding the primers, seem to remember insurgents making them from mercury fulminate and some other less stable chemicals.  Basic process was to produce the primer pellet, punch out old primer, remove anvil, flatten firing pin dent, insert pellet, put anvil back in and reprime cartridge case.

Comment: @Blackbeagle cartrige reloading is done routinely by scrooge hunters here, it's pretty robust if done accurately. As for chemicals used by those insurgents, I think those reflects logistics of their specific situation. There are many ways to provide a spark, we can just assume that it would be done. Electro-priming would, for example, significantly simplify gun design.

Comment: @Daerdemandt - There's actually a story from David Weber about a high-tech marine unit dropped on a barbarian world where their rail gun type weapons became unusable except for the prince - who had a 50 cal old fashioned cartridge weapon with electro primers.

Comment: @Beofett we still ocasionally find WW2 remains in the marshes of Eastern Europe that are usable after some "postprocessing", and just this year I used military surplus ammo manufactured in late 1970s. 2-3 decades is not enough for current supplies to degrade, and *especially* in a postapocalyptic event it's unreasonable to expect ammo and guns to be very scarce - as the global quantity of weaponry stays mostly the same (even if half of it gets expended in a huge war) but the number of people decreases 100-1000 times, the ratio of available bullets per person would be larger than nowadays.

Comment: @Peteris which is precisely why I was looking for a way to categorically disable them.  In the county where I live, there are tens of thousands of firearms sold in a single year.  Plus a lot of people here stockpile ammo, or load their own (and have supplies to continue doing so for very long periods of time).

Answer (score 8):

Since most explosives don't even need an atmosphere (you can fire guns under the water), it must a special atmosphere that is actively preventing explosions of all sorts. You could make the atmosphere to have higher density and higher viscosity. A fancier atmosphere would be one laced with super-nanobots that dissipate all motion energy to heat quickly, sort of like reverse-Maxwell's daemon.

Comment: That sounds potentially problematic for the inhabitants too, heavy thick air being hard (and tiring) to breathe

Comment: @Sam: you'd just need different lungs, at some point they'd be more like gills.

Comment: Water is vastly denser and vastly more viscous than air but, as you say, guns still fire underwater. So exactly how dense and viscous are you proposing to make your atmosphere? Of course, a dense, viscous atmosphere will vastly reduce the range at which bullets are effective. However, it will make explosives much more dangerous because the shockwaves travel more effectively in the denser medium.

Answer (score 8):

## Reduce medium range visibility

A typical way to reduce the usability of ranged weapons in general, and thus guns, is by ensuring that there is no clear line of sight from attacker to target.

This can be achieved in numerous ways, some more, some less realistic.

#### Fun solution: Weird visibility

Rather than making people invisible, let the air have a highly variable refraction index. This means you can see enemies all around you, but that you just can't point out exactly where they are. Never mind shooting them from a normal range. As a result, people may find a knife on a chain to become a more efficient weapon than a gun.

#### Realistic solution: Low visibility

Make sure that, you can't see very far. There is simply so much smog that one can just see who is walking in front of you. Once the average range of an encounter becomes small enough, people will go for swords and the like to maximize their killing potential.

---

Note that if these conditions were to be so extreme that gun usage would drop to near zero just because of them, there would be a significant impact on daily life as well. If you are just interested in disabling distance shots the impact on daily life could be fairly minimal.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the [explosive atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/61579/23150) answer, having the atmosphere be the thing that prevents firearm usage is rather implausible. If the story allows it, I would say use other factors, such as a combination of history, manufacturing practices, and *technology!*.

**Even if a single factor is unlikely to eliminate firearms and explosives, the combination of multiple factors makes it so impractical/dangerous that none would be used in favor of other weapons**

1. Technology. This one might be a major leap culturally, but technologically it's entirely possible. Consider the worldwide weapons ban mentioned below and add in a dash of government that (at least in the area your story takes place) implemented heavy [Live Fire Detection Systems](http://www.defensereview.com/anti-snipersniper-detectiongunfire-detection-systems-at-a-glance/), which detect and respond to gunshots and/or explosions. Though the Geneva convention currently prohibits computers targeting and engaging (i.e. shooting at) humans without another human pulling some sort of trigger, I'm guessing the events leading up to the apocalypse threw that out the window. Combine aforementioned LFDS with advances in [self-sustaining aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Impulse) and [laser weaponry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Weapon_System), and a sky full of drones that fry anyone that fires a bullet is entirely possible. The kinda scary thing is that it's possible *today,* it would just be expensive before the systems enjoyed the economies of scale of mass production. [South Korea's border](http://gizmodo.com/5955042/south-koreas-auto-turret-can-kill-a-man-in-the-dead-of-night-from-three-clicks) already has a gun deployed that can auto-kill a human from 3 kilometers away, and that tech isn't even cutting edge!
2. History - Consider that there is first a worldwide gun ban similar to [Australia's ban](https://www.google.com/search?q=australia%20gun%20ban&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=australia%20gun%20ban%20confiscation), which massively reduces the number of guns in the world *by physically destroying them*. After a subsequent worldwide ground conflict and a sufficient amount of time, most modern ammunition may be spent. Not 100% foolproof on its own, but making guns and ammunition rare adds to the other factors. Some regions of the world (like yours, perhaps) would likely be gun-free altogether.
3. Manufacturing - In a post-apocalyptic world, it can be assumed mass manufacturing is no longer possible. [Modern ammunition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet#The_modern_bullet) was not produced until the mid-to-late-1800s, and neither were interchangeable parts (such as barrels, magazines, revolver cylinders, etc.).  Before then, projectiles and powder were loaded into guns separately. They didn't have nearly the range or accuracy, were much heavier, and reloading was extremely slow. Practical for large-scale firing lines between standing armies, not so much for any other purpose... unless you only want one single, fairly low-accuracy shot. You can safely assume modern firearms are impossible to recreate in such a world, and who would risk a crappy musket shot when there are flying death lasers everywhere?
4. Add in pockets or "springs" of explosive gasses leaking from underground from the explosive atmosphere answer. Why not? I think it's a good idea, and credit where it is due!

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is, **no**.

Cartridges are essentially self-contained and (can be) environmentally sealed objects, very durable in every way (compared to humans or vehicles).  Nothing in the atmosphere is going to stop a cartridge from going off when primer is hit right.

A basic gun is also so simple, just barrel to contain the explosion, a lock to keep the cartridge in place, and a mechanism for a hammer to hit the primer, that nothing in atmosphere is going to prevent that from happening. Even some complex guns, such as the iconic AK47, are very robust. Tough conditions just need looser tolerances, which reduce power and accuracy, but even the most loose, but otherwise well designed gun is still going to be superior to any more primitive kintetic weapon in almost every way.

Doing "magic" with atmosphere which limits maximum velocity (like that non-newtonian fluid answer) would make existing weapons ineffective, but new ones would be rapidly designed and produced, which would fire heavier projectile with lower speed.

If you made explosive atmosphere, you would get gun designs which would cool down the explosive gasses so that they wouldn't trigger atmospheric explosion, or you would get remotely operated guns which would not be harmed by a little local atmospheric flash. Or just blast shield around the muzzle for very local flash. Or whatever. In any kind of stable (think of lightning and volcanoes) atmosphere, there's a way.

Basically, if you can shoot arrows/bolts, or just throw spears, you can make a gunpowder version, which will fire bigger projectiles more rapidly, with optimal velocity, more accurately, without it tiring you or requiring long training. The gun models we have on Earth today are optimized for our conditions, different conditions would result in different designs. But the basic advantage, the energy stored in the gunpowder, turned into kinetic energy of projectile with a twitch of a finger, "point-and-shoot", you can't hand-wave that away. If you threw modern humans with now-unuseful guns and lots of ammo into alien environmemt, they'd open the cartridges, repack them, and create ad-hoc "guns" working in that environment.

Comment: This should be the right answer. So long as we can isolate Oxidizers and reducers, there will be booms.

Answer (score 4):

All ordinary explosives are self-contained, they work totally independently of the atmosphere.  Thus the only way you can stop explosives from working with atmosphere is to have an atmospheric pressure above the detonation pressure of the explosive.  At that point when you set them off they'll get bigger because they're warmer but that's it.  The highest detonation pressure I can find is about half a million atmospheres.

Unfortunately for your story such atmospheres are not compatible with human life.  Everything becomes toxic long before this sort of pressure is reached.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe up the humidity - a lot.

A wetter, more humid atmosphere would make it harder for things to burn, and harder to ignite.  It would take more to start a spark, and more to make that spark catch something else afire.  A wetter atmosphere might have prevented the rise of firearms, as earlier versions wouldn't light when the air or accelerator was damp.

Of course, modern firearms are designed not to be so vulnerable to environmental conditions, they should be able to go off even under wet conditions.  That's sort of not the point.

*However* my point was less about firearms and more about manufacturing.  Accelerates might be designed to work independently of the atmosphere, but they have to be carefully manufactured, controlling many variables, to even get to that point.  So, if the gunpowder manufacturing plant has a hard time keeping itself dry, we can see how well bullets work packed with damp powder (or how well they don't).  Heat might help dry things, but there's a limit - and it can be pretty energy intensive.  Or dangerous, given you're working with explosives to begin with.

Of course, there will be ways to make explosives and bullets work anyway - climate control on that level takes a lot of tech but it's doable - but they will be a lot more difficult and expensive, which might be enough to make them unpopular, or put them out of price reach for average gangs.  And the tech involved (heaters, air conditioners, dehumidifiers), might be difficult to produce or maintain in a collapsed society, without a solid tech base behind it, especially since the individual skills would likely have been let lapse as luxuries, until they realized the secondary effects on manufacturing stuff like gunpowder.

Comment: For reference, getting gunpowder slightly damp actually increases its power until you get it so wet it won't light.  Water is very good at soaking up heat and turning it into pressure (hence why we build steam engines).  An excessively damp environment could still cause manufacturing issues like you suggest though.

Comment: @Perkins - ooh, neat, I didn't know that.  I was assuming wet enough to have trouble lighting, it's true.  Although even being more powerful an explosive might be its own kind of problem, if the gun in question isn't equipped for the extra explosive power in its bullets and that causes other problems - maybe it can be one more reason for guns to be dropped as unreliable in this world.

Comment: It could be an issue.  Although most guns will have enough of a safety margin to be able to handle it.  I've seen powder hammers malfunction due to the extra pressure from old cartridges that had been stored in a damp environment though, and some semi-automatic weapons don't cycle correctly unless the amount of power in the round is almost exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

If the atmosphere is thick enough, the projectiles fired will just slow down from friction very rapidly and end up falling to the ground harmlessly shortly after leaving the barrel.
Can still use the gun at short range, say a pistol at near contact range, but at longer ranges they'll be all but useless.

A bigger question is how to explain a massive increase in air pressure as having been caused by your apocalyptic event.
And of course building a world where such an extremely dense atmosphere (it'd have to be just about liquid) can exist and your creatures survive in it who previously survived in a far less dense atmosphere. The atmospheric pressure would be immense, and their bodies probably incapable in dealing.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have some kind of electrical/static field in the air that would penetrate the bullet casing causing the gun power to ignite prematurely.
Even just building a bullet, it would explode seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Memming gave an awesome idea about nano-bots, buts it gets problematic with motion-preventing, affecting everything that moves. My idea would be nanobots infesting the atmosphere in a way that they sense gunpowder or other explosives (extremely sensive AI-like bots) and render all encasings and shells unusable, entering ammunition and changing propelents and explosives structure at molecular level etc. Well, this approach depends on how high-tech and Sci-Fi-ish you wanna get.

Answer (score 1):

Invent some molecules, able to quickly stick to iron (or whatever metals gunbarrels can be made of) and create thin film on it. (These molecules probably must not cause harm to most plants and animals.)

Then, two possibilities. If such film is thick and hard enough, then shooting will be problematic, gun may explode or bullet speed will be very low. If it is not, then it may change its properties after exposing to high pressure and/or temperature and for example bind enough something from atmosphere after shooting and making guns unusable again.

Comment: Just coat your moving parts in tin or copper then.  Or even plastic.  Keep the iron inside for strength.

Comment: I rather thought about reusing existing guns - sure you can find some new material, resistant to my 'corrosion' and suitable for guns.

Comment: Copper plating could be added to existing, simple guns with a minimum of effort.  There are even ones currently being manufactured with various kinds of metal or plastic coatings to prevent corrosion when they get carried in someone's sweaty shoulder holster all day.  Your idea has some merit, it just needs a bit of expansion and tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way at coming at it which might suit an apocalyptic scenario would be the occurrence of a universal and severe allergic reaction to explosives. It would make making ammunition very difficult in a technologically regressed world, while firing a weapon would be virtually suicidal (as the residue would spread through a fair amount of the local atmosphere)

Answer (score 0):

As other posters noted explosives often work totally independently of the atmosphere since they contain everything needed to explode.

How about making explosives much more sensitive because of some sort of radiation. If this radiation is present globally (atmosphere with radioactive particles for example) it would make really hard to create and carry explosives safely. While local radiation would prevent use of explosives in critical areas because they would explode on borders of radiated area.

Local radiation could be also from atmosphere or from some radiation generator. Radiation should be harmless to life, like electromagnetic waves that are all around us.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how this radiation would make explosions more sensitive without also making, e.g., the sugar molecules within your body much more willing to decompose.

Comment: True, but we are bombarded daily by many types of  particles, some of them stop immediatelly while some go through earth without notice, all of them have some kind of impact already, so there is possibility to find one.

Comment: I don't understand how your response relates to my comment. Your body and explosions both work in essentially the same way: they involve chemical reactions that need a small amount of energy to trigger them and, once that's happened, the reaction releases more energy than you just put in. How do you propose to make the chemical reactions of guncotton (chemically, essentially sugar plus nitro groups) much more sensitive without also making the chemical reactions in my body (essentially, sugar minus nitro groups) not also go haywire?

Comment: And how is this mechanism going to deal with the explosives that don't look like nitrated sugars, such as nitroglycerine (essentially nitrated alcohol), TNT (nitrated paint thinner), RDX (which doesn't fit in to the pattern of "essentially something you're familiar with, plus nitro groups"), gunpowder (essentially coal plus an oxidizer), ...

Comment: Well it is up to OP to present it in a way to make any sense. I am not a chemist to reason about it deeper. I just think that since radiation has no problem to go through explosive material and shell casings it is more plausible than other solutions since explosives work independently from atmosphere. But your points are valid

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a chemical could be added to make the atmosphere a non-Newtonian fluid (like oobleck, except a gas). This make it difficult to exert force on the air around you, maybe not enough to make running hard.

the most obvious effect will be that bullets, with incredibly high velocity, will slow and fall to ground much quicker.

I think this may also mean that vibrations in the air will be dampened, such to reduce the effects of an explosion. It may also make shouting or producing loud sounds difficult.

Comment: Wouldn't a non-Newtonian atmosphere make explosions more powerful? Water (more viscous) transmits shock waves much better than air (less viscous).

Comment: Thats a good question, and I don't exactly know the answer, but my instinct would tell me, that non-Newtonian fluids behave solid, and solids usually dampen explosives. at the very least, shrapnel would be slowed just as a bullet would.

Answer (score 0):

### Weather

Some other answers suggest adding humidity to prevent combustion. This is a terrible idea, as has been stated. However, it could work for a different reason, especially if we add some sand.

#### Firearms can be unreliable

Or, at least, the modern version, with high effective ranges and fancy concepts such as "semi-automation". More simple weapons aren't quite, though.

The most basic version of a gun (as we think of it) is as follows:

- Take a projectile.
- Stick it in a fireproof tube.
- Make an explosion that launches the projectile out of the tube at a high velocity.

This can be an improvement over bows and the likes at very short ranges, if your goal is piercing armor, but it's very unreliable at longer ranges. Guns of this sort have been around since around the 1100s, and the basic gist of it wasn't drastically improved upon until around the 1850s or so. They were mostly used for armor-piercing purposes and due to needing much, much, *much* less training to use effectively than a bow at similar ranges. However, they were exceedingly inaccurate and took long to load.

These would still be viable, but only due to simplicity... and even then, only to an extent. Though, I suppose the title of this subsection is somewhat innacurate...

#### MODERN firearms can be unreliable.

One of the more popular handguns in pop culture is the **Desert Eagle.** While it may look cool and sound nice, it's really a terrible weapon. It's incredibly heavy (making it hard to hold steady for aiming), and jams exceedingly frequently, especially in humid or sandy areas (ironically making it useless in deserts). Despite all that, it's also WAY more expensive than most other guns (just under $2000 USD) - you can buy actual, military-grade, melt-through-steel-in-an-instant laser weapons for around that price.

Most firearms are, to an extent, similar, anymore.

Guns, these days, are astoundingly intricate. If I tell you to go make a .44 Magnum, you wouldn't be able to. If I went to someone who regularly machines things as a hobby and told them to make one, they wouldn't be able to either. Only a huge assembly process specifically created for the production of .44 Magnums would be able to make one with any efficiency, because there's just *so many tiny parts that all need to be perfect to even get off one shot.*

As such, even if I already have an assembled, working .44 Magnum, it can still have issues firing if it gets full of sand or starts to rust or the likes. And a good, old-fashioned revolver is one of the most reliable weapons you can own - just imagine what it's like for even *more* complex weapons with 35 extra parts for feeding an ammo belt and another 12 for ejecting spent cartridges, 17 for feeding in new bullets from a clip, et cetera.

#### Let's just get to the point already

Now imagine some incredibly-humid, sandy-as-all-getout land where so much action goes on that you'd never be able to sit down and do maintenance even half as often as you should under good conditions. Within ten years, nearly all complex firearms would be so rusted and ruined that they could never fire a single bullet again.

Now, as for explosives...

#### There's just no stopping explosives

A bomb is even more simple than a gun.

- Get something that can explode
- There is no step two

People make bombs with a quarter-cup of laundry detergent, an empty milk jug, a piece of flint and some metal to hit it against. These are effective enough to be as costly to troops fighting in a war than the actual "fighting in a war" bit. Making the air more wet isn't going to stop it. Making the air amplify that explosion *just makes it an even MORE attractive option!* There's just no stopping bombs without deoxygenating the atmosphere. Sorry.

Comment: I think "most firearms" today is still AK47 and its clones. Rather reliable, rather easy to make, due to rather loose tolerances. Yet also not too inaccurate.

Comment: [citation needed] for the claim that there are cheap, effective laser weapons in the world today. And you seem to misunderstand explosives: explosives don't require atmospheric oxygen. Old fashioned explosives such as gunpowder already contain oxidizers; modern explosives (TNT, nitroglycerine, C4, anything) contain everything you need within a single molecule.

Comment: Building a working, .44 magnum revolver would only require machining tolerances of about 1/1000 of an inch.  Anyone who can't achieve that doesn't deserve to call themselves a metalworker.  Good metalworkers have been able to do it since the middle ages.  I have successfully made replacement gun parts with nothing more than a piece of steel, a hacksaw, and a good file.  It's a slow, tedious process, but there's nothing magic about it. Designing a working revolver from scratch would be slightly more challenging, but anyone who can build a model steam engine could do it with a bit of effort.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah, I tried to find a good citation, but I can't exactly remember where. Honestly, I read about it in a Cracked article. If it bugs you too much, I can remove it.

Comment: @Perkins Yeah, I'm aware deoxygenation won't stop explosives definitively. I'm just saying, there's *no* stopping them. I just tried to put that into perspective.

As for the .44, well, I suppose you make a good point. We *are* talking about the post-apocalypse here, though, so who's to say there's the necessary skills and tools among the world's denizens?

Comment: @Papayaman1000  It depends on the cause of the apocalypse and how much of the infrastructure is left over.  There have been repeating and cartridge-based gunpowder weapons since at least the time of Henry VIII.  A good apocalypse will probably result in a lot of muzzleloaders made from scavenged water pipe in the period between when the supplies of modern weapons run out and when the metals infrastructure gets built up to 1300s levels again.  Assuming people can hold onto their knowledge.  That's much harder to develop than metallurgy. Especially where nobody has it on paper anymore.

Comment: @Perkins I dunno, to me "apocalypse" means a significant portion of the planet's dominant species (at least 90%, more like 95-100%) being wiped out, and what that entails (i.e. large munitions factories being rendered unusable due to lack of maintenance, nuclear plants without emergency shutdowns exploding, The Netherlands getting washed out to sea [or taking over the world], etc.). I also included the likelihood that most modern knowledge, being highly interdependent, would be lost due to specialization and world economics making all the necessary professionals hard to gather into one place.

Comment: ...if we keep this up, it's gonna get moved to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not see you can stop the guns themselves from working without radical changes affecting all normal life, but perhaps if you make use of guns very dangerous for the person using the the gun it could achieve the same result.

One avenue of thought might be something in the air which reacts violently with exhaust gases from shells created when bullet is fired. It might be chemical reaction, or it might be biological agents or nanobots which activates when those specific fumes are present (as most of normal life uses does not smell like gunshots, it would not create problems in normal person life, unlike most of the suggested answers)

Answer (score -1):

Forgive me science if this is too absurd.

Disperse into the atmosphere molecules with 2 characteristics:

1. Their atomic nuclei are unstable enough to be smashed together (nuclear fusion) if they impact other molecules in the air at velocities that a bullet pushing the air can cause. Make the energy released enough to smash the bullet.
2. The new element produced by the [nuclear transmutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation) is solid and strong enough to mostly contain the released energy (so that the energy release is localized and doesn't eg destroy the entire town).

Now when a bullet is fired the air pushes back and smashes the bullet then solidifies into a small ball which falls to the ground. You might even have it [decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay) in some days or weeks back into the first element so the supply in the atmosphere stays more or less constant.

You probably have to invent a couple exotic chemical elements to make this work.

Comment: And the first big volcanic eruption that happens will have *really* interesting effects...  Not to mention the multiple tons of meteors that come screaming down every year...

Comment: This seems to break conservation of momentum. You initially have a forward moving bullet, a bit of nuclear fusion happens and suddenly the fusion products are falling downwards.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use millimeter waves to basically turn any matter into liquid, decompose the electron magnetism or extinguish flames if that's what you're after. It's a powerful wave and this device is theoretical ,but not particularly difficult to comprehend. It uses a series of magnetrons and a series of pulse guns oscillating at or greater than 192ghz targeted at the gun using a laser guide.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like the [Active Denial System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System), but at a different wavelength. I don't know about turning matter into liquid or putting out fires, but I've been hit by the ADS ('hey guys, go stand over there on that spot for just a minute....') and I'm still mostly solid, although it does make you itchy. Do you care to give more references to this equipment?

Answer (score -3):

Explosives are unusable if there is no oxygen, you are right on that one. However, guns can work even in a vacuum, as there is enough oxygen inside the bullet casing to allow for the chemical reaction inside them to take place. However, since it is a post-apocalyptic universe, newer bullets that are not made inside areas that have an atmospheric composition similar to that of the Earth will be unusable since there will be no oxygen to allow for their respective chemical reactions.

Comment: While it's true that guns and bullets need oxygen (or any oxidizer really) to function, the ozidizer is rarely (if ever) atmospheric oxygen, usually something like a perchlorate or nitrate is used as an oxidizer (some hobby rockets use just sugar and potassium nitrate - to make it explode instead, just turn it into a fine loose powder and bingo), when it's heated it releases far more oxygen than the same volume of air, more oxygen means a bigger bang.

Comment: Ah thank you, I wasn't entirely aware.

Comment: That's ok, it's not what I'd call common knowledge anyway

Comment: It's NOT common knowledge that gunpowder contains oxgyen bonded within chemicals, and the general public thinks it has something to do with atmospheric free oxygen!?!?!?!?!?!!?!?! I'm highly skeptical and mind blown...

Comment: Sorry Nora, but this answer if factually incorrect, and I should mark that for others.

Comment: Still, leave it around, I learned something reading it and the associated answers. (I'm always fascinated by how much there is to learn about very diverse subjects just reading worldbuilding's answers and comments)

Comment: @ErikE  Considering that Britain actually considered dropping highschool chemistry programs as part of their anti-terrorism kick to prevent people from learning how to make bombs, it's actually surprising how many people know how guns actually work in the modern world.

Comment: @Perkins That's crazy!